# Finding all combinations where each digit is picked from a different set

Tags: python, combinatorics

I need to generate every combination of a sequence of digits where each digit can be picked from a finite set.

For example:

(1|2), (1|2), (2|3), (2|3), (2|3), (3|4|5)

Where the first digit can be a 1 or a 2, and the last digit can be a 3, 4, or 5.

1,2,2,3,2,4 would be a valid combination, but 3,2,2,3,2,4 wouldn't.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does exactly that:

```
import itertools

for x in itertools.product('12','12','23','23','23','345'):
    print(', '.join(x))
```